# How many times a while loop get executed?

Tags: algorithm

Yesterday I applied for computer engineering master degree and it was the one of the their questions. I could not solve it so I was very curious.

```
...
i = 1;
while (i <= n)
{
    i = i * 2;
}
...
```

How many times will this while loop get executed, please give your answer as a formula. For ex: log n...

Thanks

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, please tag as such and show us your own attempt at the solution.

Comment: @Niklas B. no it is not homework... i explained it in my question

Comment: @Killercam: The solution sought is not a number but a function of `n`, as the OP says ("for ex: log n").

Comment: @Killercam n is defined out of the scope but we don't know its value... so our answer must be as a formula...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the x<sup>th</sup> iteration of the loop, `i` equals 2<sup>x</sup> (you can easily prove this by induction). Suppose the loop stops after X iterations, which means n < 2<sup>X</sup>. This also means that on iteration X-1 the loop was still running and so 2<sup>X-1</sup> ≤ n. In other words :

2<sup>X-1</sup> ≤ n < 2<sup>X</sup>

From there, finding X as a function of log<sub>2</sub>(n) is easy.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've studied Maths, so I don't know how I can calculate...

Comment: @zafiyet: You follow a strange logic there. If you've studied math, you should be able to calculate that

Comment: There is a problem with it, calculating the integer part, I think the question says "how many times" you can't answer with a double (not to mention a Real number)..

Comment: @Hernan: The additional operation you'll need is the floor function

Comment: @NiklasB. I did not see a connection between i and n in the interview, so I was curious and I asked this question for learning. Do you have any problem with this?

Comment: @zafiyet: Absolutely not. I just wondered about the implication "studied math => cannot calculate"

Comment: @NiklasB. Right the answer about how many, is floor( log2(n) )